# Django Filter Query on Listview

Tags: python, django

I have a case that needs to show that the user will expire in 1 month and user has already joined below 1 month, on the view.

Here is what my `template.html` looks like:

```
+-------------------------------------+  +-------------------------------------+
| Member will Expired in 30 days      |  | New Member Almost 30 Days           |
+-------------------------------------+  +-------------------------------------+
| Name            | Expired in        |  | Name            | 1 Month in        | 
+-------------------------------------+  +-------------------------------------+
| John            | 12 Hours          |  | Alex            | 12 Hours          |
| Doe             | 10 Days           |  | Monroe          | 12 Days           |
| Sue             | 30 Days           |  | Zax             | 28 Days           |
+-------------------------------------+  +-------------------------------------+
```

here my `template.html` code

```
...
{% for a in dashboards %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ a.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ a.membership_till|naturaltime }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
...    

...
{% for a in dashboards %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ a.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ a.membership_till|naturaltime }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
...
```

here my `model.py`

```
class User(models.Model):
    ...
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    joined_date = models.DateTimeField(max_length=255)
    membership_till = models.DateTimeField(max_length=255)
    ...
```

here my `views.py`

```
class DashboardListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    context_object_name = 'dashboards'
    model = models.User
```

Currently, I can only show all the data on the two table without filtering.

I need to show 2 `<table>` with 2 different functions, but I don't have an idea how to filter on `template.html`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well like the name `ListView` suggests, the view is actually made to only work with *one* queryset. In case however you want to work with more elements, you can **patch the `get_context_data`** function:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class DashboardListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    context_object_name = 'dashboards'
    model = models.User

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(DashboardListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

        now = datetime.now()
        d30 = timedelta(30)
        context['expire'] = User.objects.filter(membership_till__lt=now+d30)
        context['new'] = User.objects.filter(joined_date__gt=now-d30)

        return context
```

So we add two extra querysets to the context, and then we can use those in the `template.html`:

```
...
{% for a in expire %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ a.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ a.membership_till|naturaltime }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
...    

...
{% for a in new %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ a.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ a.membership_till|naturaltime }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
...
```

Comment: thank you, its work. so if i want add more filter just add `context['anotherfilter'] ` ? `context` in here is unlimited?

Comment: @DickyRaambo: yes `context` is a dictionary, and as long as the key is unique, you can extend it. But note that a listview is not really made for this.